# Counting number of different object types in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, counting

For this program I have an arraylist for animals full of objects from two subclasses (Fish and Tiger class)  I am having a hard time figuring out how to count each item type so I can print it out. I need it to say something like There are 3 tigers and 2 fish.
Here is my code thus far

```
import java.util.*;
public class Menagerie{
   public static void main(String [] args){
      /* ArrayList to hold animal data */
      ArrayList<Animal> alist = new ArrayList<Animal>();
      /* object creations */
      Tiger jtiger = new Tiger("Javan Tiger", "Tiger acreage #6");
      Fish fnfish = new Fish("False network catfish", "Fresh Water");
      Tiger btiger = new Tiger("Bengal tiger", "Ritchie area of RIT");
      Fish shark = new Fish("Shark", "Salt Water");
      Tiger stiger = new Tiger("Siberian Tiger", "Tiger acreage #4");

      /* Adding objects to alist ArrayList */

      alist.add(jtiger);
      alist.add(fnfish);
      alist.add(btiger);
      alist.add(shark);
      alist.add(stiger);

      /* printing out animal information using toString() */

      System.out.println("Report on animals...");
      System.out.println(jtiger.toString());
      System.out.println(fnfish.toString());
      System.out.println(btiger.toString());
      System.out.println(shark.toString());
      System.out.println(stiger.toString());





   }


}
```

Any help will be great! thanks.

Comment: Just loop through the `alist` and test the instanceof each Object

Comment: `instanceof` operator: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 4):

1.) Iterate over `alist`.

```
for(Animal animal : alist){

}
```

2.) Have two counters, one for `tigerCount` and another for `fishCount`.

3.) Check for `instanceOf class`, and `increment` accordingly.

```
  for(Animal animal : alist){
        if(animal instanceOf Fish){
              fishCount++;

         }else if(animal instanceOf Tiger){
             tigerCount++;
         }
    }
```

[instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) keyword is a binary operator used to test if an object (instance) is a subtype of a given Type.

> **instanceof** operator is used to check the type of an object at runtime.
>   It is the means by which your program can obtain run-time type
>   information about an object. instanceof operator is also important in
>   case of casting object at runtime. instanceof operator return **boolean**
>   value, if an object reference is of specified type then it return **true**
>   otherwise **false**.

Comment: Thank you, that was a big help and I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

A more generically applicable solution is this:

```
// Map captures {Type => #Animals}
Map<String,Integer> animalCount = new HashMap<>();
for( Animal animal : alist )
  {
    String className = animal.getClass().getName();
    Integer count = animalCount.get( className );
    if( count == null )
      {
        // First time we've seen this type of Animal
        animalCount.put( className, 1 );
      }
    else
      {
        // We've seen this type of Animal at least once
        animalCount.put( className, count + 1 );
      }
  }

// Print out a series of lines like "There were 7 Tiger(s)"
for( Map.Entry<String,Integer> reportRow : animalCount.entrySet() )
  {
    System.out.println( "There were "+reportRow.getValue() + " " + reportRow.getKey()+"(s)" );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a minimal compilable example, so it doesn't use your pre-existing classes.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

        //create animals
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            animals.add(new Dog());
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            animals.add(new Cat());
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            animals.add(new Cow());

        //create HashMap with class type as key
        Map<String, Integer> types = new HashMap<>();

        for (Animal a : animals) {
            Integer count = types.get(a.getClass().getSimpleName());
            //if count is null then we need to create a new entry with the value of 1
            //otherwise just increase count and replace
            types.put(a.getClass().getSimpleName(), count == null ? 1 : ++count);
        }

        //go through each entry and print it out
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> x : types.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(x.getKey() + " -> Total " + x.getValue());
        }
    }

    //ignore static. just because i'm using main method
    static class Animal{}
    static class Dog extends Animal{}
    static class Cat extends Animal{}
    static class Cow extends Animal{}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Java8 version if you like

```
    Map<Class<? extends Animal>, List<Animal>> counted = alist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(anmial -> {
        if (anmial instanceof Tiger) return Tiger.class;
        if (anmial instanceof Fish) return Fish.class;
        return null;
    }));

    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("There are {0} tigers and {1} fishes", counted.get(Tiger.class).size(), counted.get(Fish.class).size()));
```

Look at the java docs for more detail: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html